# como hacer un INNER JOIN y mostrar en php

Tags: php, mysql

> Tabla notas con los siguientes campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que sale el ID de alumno, y necesito traer el nombre del alumno de la tabla `alumnos`

actualmente tengo mi consulta en php de la siguiente forma:

```
    $getNotas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM notas WHERE grupo='$grupo'") or die ('error al obtener datos de notas');
```

¿como puedo traer los nombres de los alumnos de la otra tabla.

He intentado utilizar mas no sé bien sí esta bien estructurado

```
$getNotas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT
        nt.ID NOTA_ID ,
        nt.grupo grupo,
        nt.unidad_1 unidad1,
        nt.unidad_2 unidad2,
        nt.unidad_3 unidad3,
        nt.unidad_4 unidad4,
        al.ID ALUMNO_ID,
        al.nombre nombrealumno, FROM notas nt INNER JOIN alumnos al ON nt.NOTA_ID = al.ALUMNO_ID WHERE nt.grupo='$grupo'") or die ('error al obtener datos de notas'.mysqli_connect_error());
```

Manda el mensaje de "error al obtener datos de notas". no tiene errores de sintaxis, pero no me muestra nada.

Comment: investigue un poco sobre el tema, se que es para traer informacion de otras tablas una consulta multiple, pero la verdad esque no se como realizarla.

Comment: Voto negativo a tu pregunta debido a que como @sstan comenta, deberías tratar de informarte sobre como realizar un INNER JOIN, el cuál no es nada difícil, sin embargo es indignante que en lugar de investigar sobre el tema, realices una pregunta para que te regalen el código, yo te regalo un link en donde explican todo muy bien [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: gracias por tu voto alexchvrches, vengo aqui por orientacion ya he realizado varias pruebas y no me ha dado por eso he recurrido aquí, no soy un experto en bdd. pero igual gracias!

Comment: ya he modificado.

Comment: manda el mensaje de "error al obtener datos de notas". no tiene errores de sintaxis, pero no me muestra nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primera vista, tu consulta está bien construida. El detalle principal parece ser con tu condición de join:

```sql
ON nt.ID = al.id_alumno
```

Es necesario que hagas el join con las columnas de ambas tablas que corresponden al ID de alumno. `nt.ID` no parece ser eso, mas bien parece ser el ID de la nota.

No tengo claro cuales son los nombres de las columnas en tu tabla `notas`, pero la condición debería mas bien ser algo así:

```sql
ON nt.alumno = al.id_alumno
```

... donde `nt.alumno` corresponde a la columna en la tabla `notas` que contiene el ID de alumno. Ajusta el nombre de la columna de ser necesario.

**Edición**

Bueno, tal vez hay otros pequeños ajustes que necesitarás hacer además de lo mencionado arriba:

1. `nt.nombre alumno,`: No parece correcto que `nt.nombre` corresponda al nombre del alumno. A menos que esto represente algún otro dato necesario, elimínalo de la consulta. El nombre de alumno ya lo recuperas con `al.nombre nombrealumno`.
2. `nt.ID ID` y `al.id_alumno ID`: Estás asignando el alias `ID` a 2 columnas con significados diferentes. Para evitar problemas, asígnales aliases diferentes. Ejemplo: `nt.ID NOTA_ID` y `al.id_alumno ALUMNO_ID`.
3. `al.unidad4 unidad_4`: Esto es un error. Debería ser: `nt.unidad4 unidad_4`.

Comment: he modificado los datos como me has dicho sigue sin mostrarme nada. ¿es necesario la relacion entre tablas? aun no la relaciono.

Comment: Sí es necesario la relación y debe ser un detalle bien pequeñó lo que te falta.. ¿Puedes agregar tu último intento a la pregunta? Alternativamente, si puedes tratar de correr la consulta directamente en MySQL. Si hay error, lo verás más claro desde allí.

Comment: he echo la consulta, con un select simple era muy facil mostrar la informacion así: **<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>** pero ahora como es que viene la información. por ejemplo, si quisiera mostrar el nombre del alumno como debería ir?

Comment: Si tu consulta actual todavía se parece a la que tienes en la pregunta, sería `$row['nombrealumno']`.